# BigCommerce Add Global Variable

Tags: bigcommerce

I added user created custom field for customer sign up - "UPS Shipper".
And I want to show this value in Invoice email.
But it is impossible, for we can use only global variables and language variables in that email template, there is no variable for that custom added form field.
So I think it should be added a global variable for that field.

I'm not sure I'm right.
Please let me know how to add a global variable in bigcommerce.
Or let me know what I think wrong.

Best regards

Lorant

Answer (score 1):

global variables are defined in the PHP and since Bigcommerce is a SaaS platform you will not be able to add that variable at all.

You may suggest that the customer can log in to their account to view the custom information if they need.